# "do shell script" fails with complaint about "env" and "No such file or directory" but the path for the command is correct

Tags: terminal, applescript

Background: *texdoc* is a command installed by the LaTeX distribution MacTeX and `which texdoc` in the Terminal gives "/Library/TeX/texbin/texdoc".

In the Terminal, `texdoc --version` gives:

*Texdoc 3.4.1 (2022-03-19)*.

But in AppleScript, via `do shell script`, this didn't work.

`do shell script "/Library/TeX/texbin/texdoc --version"` gives the error:

**error** "env: texlua: No such file or directory" number 127.

I don't understand why AppleScript speak about "texlua" not found and "env" (by the way `which texlua` gives "/Library/TeX/texbin/texlua").

How to call `texdoc` with `do shell script`?

**Edit**

In fact, not only I can not call directly `texdoc --version`, but after this is resolved by append `/Library/TeX/texbin:` to the path, a real usage case is still not working, eg `do shell script "texdoc url"`, even if I append `/Library/TeX/texbin:` to the path. Applescript complaints that it does not find the `open` command (`open` is called by `texdoc` to display the pdf documentation. Very strange, because when called directly, eg `do shell script "open /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf"`, this works.

So, after adding `export PATH='/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH';`, the AppleScript code :

```
do shell script "export PATH='/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH'; texdoc url"
```

outputs this error:

**error** "sh: open: command not found\rtexdoc error: Failed to execute: open "/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf"" number 1

So what is the complete method to call a binary like `texdoc` with AppleScript?

Comment: FWIW, the shell used here has a different environment than that of the Terminal. Try running `env` in the terminal and then run it in Script Editor with `do shell script "env"`. Note especially the difference in PATH. Then try `do shell script "which tex"` and compare. For some explanation by apple, take a look at their tech note on the subject: [TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html). You can do most stuff, you just need to take this into account.

Comment: /Library/TeX/texbin/texdoc is probably a shell script that depends on other scripts/programs in /Library/TeX/texbin. That directory is in your `PATH` in an interactive shell, but not in the shell that `do shell script` creates. Try `do shell script "PATH="/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH"; texdoc --version"`

Comment: @Mockman Among differences, in the Terminal, **env** outputs `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin` and by AppleScript, I obtain only `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. For **which tex** I obtain `/Library/TeX/texbin/tex` in the Terminal and the error `"The command exited with a non-zero status." number 1` in AppleScript. But why my command doesn't work when I append the complete path to the CLI command?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes your command command works (by replacing the inners `"`with `'`), thanks, but why doesn't my version works despite I have append the complete path to the command?

Comment: @Mockman The command that doesn't work is `do shell script "/Library/TeX/texbin/texdoc --version"`. Why, because I have append the complete path to it (/Library/TeX/texbin/texdoc is the complete path). What is the difference with `do shell script "PATH="/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH"; texdoc --version"` suggested by Gordon Davisson, and works? Moreover, but I probably need to ask another question (?), if I try `do shell script "PATH='/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH'; texdoc url"`, yet it's the "open" command which isn't found (`texdoc` call  `open` to display the PDF "url.pdf" in Preview app).

Comment: What do you get with this? `do shell script "export PATH=\"/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH\" ; echo $PATH"` Your command doesn't include the `export`. I think the same path will be returned either way but I'm not sure that the path will be available to any subsequent commands without the export.

Comment: @Mockman This returns "/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin". And what must I do as I discover that in fact, if do shell script "texdoc --version"  is solved by adding "PATH='/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH';" before, this don't resolve a real usage case (replacing "--version" with a LaTeX package, eg "url"). Must I edit my question? Ask another question? `do shell script "export PATH='/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH'; texdoc url"` gives this error: "sh: open: command not found\rtexdoc error: Failed to execute: open \"/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf\"" number 1.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe the actual problem, and include any output you get as well.

Comment: Note that since the default shell environment is does not have _any_ of your changes,  _everything_ running in that shell will have the same issue.

Comment: @nohillside Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first line of `/Library/TeX/texbin/texdoc`

```
$ head -1 /Library/TeX/texbin/texdoc
#!/usr/bin/env texlua
```

calls `texlua` and relies on `env` finding the command within `PATH`. As AppleScripts run with the default path (which doesn't contain `/Library/TeX/texbin`) this will fail with the error you see.

To solve, use

```
do shell script "PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH texdoc --version"
```

instead which makes sure `PATH` includes your texbin directory.

Comment: Applescript doesn't understand single-quotes; you need to use double-quotes around the entire command, and escape the inner double-quotes with backslashes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson In fact, we can alsot invert `'` and `"`.  `do shell script "PATH='/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH'; texdoc --version"` works. So we don't have to use `\"`. But I have discovered that if with this trick, `texdoc --version` works, in real usage case, eg `texdoc url`, as this call the command `open` to display the PDF of the documentation, AppleScrip says "sh: open: command not found" (but used directly, open is found, eg `do shell script "/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf"` works. Why AppleScript don't find the path of "open" when called by "texdoc"?

Comment: @quark67 The version with single-quotes won't work because the shell won't expand `$PATH` when it's in single-quotes. The original `PATH` didn't include `/Library/TeX/texbin`, so it couldn't find programs there (other than the one you specifically pointed at); with single-quotes, `PATH` effectively *only* contains `/Library/TeX/texbin`, so it can't find programs anywhere else. It may or may not need to find programs in the usual places, but if it ever does it'll fail. Basically, you haven't noticed a problem with single-quotes, but that doesn't mean they actually work.

Comment: @GordonDavisson You are right, and yet it works. I wasn't aware of the difference between `'` and `"`. So I accept the answer from nohillside who has provided a working solution (but a have not seen it before, because I believed that `\"` can be replaced with `'`).

Comment: @nohillside, can you insist in your answer that it is very important to do not use `'`, but `\"`? Forgetting this give the weird error I have encountered. This will probably help others.

Comment: @quark67 unless a path entry contains a space character, you need neither.